# Is there official document about what SQL flink supports

Tags: apache-flink

I looked through Flink official documentation ,but didn't find what kinds of SQL that flink has supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink’s SQL support is based on Apache Calcite, which implements the SQL standard. The SQL support is not yet feature complete, but lately each new release has brought some exciting new features -- such as temporal tables and match_recognize, which were added in Flink 1.7.

I believe [this part of the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql.html#supported-syntax) provides the details you are looking for.

For learning how to work with Flink SQL, I recommend the [Apache Flink® SQL Training](https://github.com/dataArtisans/sql-training/wiki) on github.

Comment: Great,thanks. Actually, I don't think https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql.html#supported-syntax has provided all the features that Flink SQL supports, eg: Case/When exppression, it doesn't mention it,but Flink supports this.